# Удалить слова, встречающиеся один раз из массива строк

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив строк, нужно удалить НЕповторяющиеся элементы.
Нашла минималистичный код для удаления повторяющихся элементов:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str));
String[] result = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```

Но из-за его минималистичности не могу понять, каким образом преобразовать его в то, что нужно мне.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код, который вы нашли, ничего толком не дает (относительно вашей задачи). По сути, о нем можно просто забыть. Самый простой вариант "в лоб" сделать следующее:

Допустим вы имеет список (List) строк (то есть перевели массив в список) с именем `input`, тогда:

- Создаете `Map`, где ключом является тип `String`, а значением `Integer`. Делаете цикл по списку и складываете в `Map` таким образом, чтобы в `String` ключе лежало строковое значение, а в `Integer` - количество повторений данной строки.

  Обычно это проверяется так:

  - Нет такого ключа? Тогда заносим его в `Map` и ставим счетчик (Integer) в 0.
  - Есть такой ключ? Тогда увеличиваем счетчик (Integer) в существующем значении на 1

  Если у вас список будет со значениями `test, yo, test, ok, yo, test, hello`, то на выходе должны получить:

  ```
  Ключ   Значение
  ---------------
  test      2
  yo        2
  ok        1
  hello     1
  ```
- На втором шаге заводите результирующий список (result) и делаете еще раз цикл `for` **с конца** (это важно!) изначального заданного списка (input), до его начала и проверяете:

  Какое число повторений занесено в `Map` со значением, которое сейчас выдается в итерации? Если больше 1, то заносите его в результирующий список.

Всё.

Дальше, если нужно, переводите список в массив.

---

Не удержался. С помощью стримов:

```
// Входные данные
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("test", "yo", "ok",
                                                        "test", "hello",
                                                        "eak", "hello", 
                                                        "test", "eak"));
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Подсчитываем сколько раз встречается значение в списке
Map<String, Long> result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
// Удаляем из списка элементы, встречающиеся только один раз
list.removeIf(s -> result.get(s).intValue() == 1);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Output
System.out.println(list); // [test, test, hello, eak, hello, test, eak]
```

Без промежуточной переменной (`Map<String, Long>`):

```
list.removeIf(
        s -> list.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
            ).get(s).intValue() == 1
);
```

Почитать подробно про **[stream API](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/270383/)**

Comment: а можно ли как-то преобразовать result в обычный список, содержащий только повторяющиеся элементы (в единственном экземпляре), без ключей со значениями вхождений?

Comment: @ВикторияПушкина так как для начала идет промежуточная выборка, чтобы выяснить какие элементы в единственном экземпляре, а какие дублируются - то надо в любом случае создать `Map<String, Long>` где результат такой операции будет лежать.... можешь назвать его не `result`, а `intermediate` )) но если тебе нужна переменная, которая будет содержать только повторяющиеся элементы, но в единственном экземпляре, то тут на помощь действительно придет `Set` и `Hashmap` ......`Set myFinalResult  = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(list));` -  где list - это в моем ответе переменная `list`

Answer (score 5):

```
Set set = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(str));
```

Set - коллекция уникальных элементов, т.е. там нет одинаковых)

```
String[] result = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```

тут идет обычное преобразование сета в массив. В итоге result - массив всех элементов без их дубликатов.
Т.е. если было `"абв" "а" "абв" "б" "с" "а"` то станет `"абв" "а" "б" "с"`

Попробуйте решение в лоб - преобразовать массив в `allStringsList`, в цикле перебрать элементы, посмотреть у каких нету повторений, закинуть их в какой-то отдельный `uniqueElementsList` и потом сделать `allStringsList.removeAll(uniqueElementsList)`